# Roles Comparison in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[Authorize(Roles="ABC")]
public class HelloController : Controller
{
   //
   // GET: /Hello/
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Here, Users with "ABC" role can access the Hellocontroller.
My Question is with what MVC will compare the role type "ABC"?

Comment: If you are using the simple membership, this string will be compared with All roles assined to the authenticated user.

Comment: var role = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(); I checked how many roles assigned to the authenitcated user. It yield me null

Comment: Have a read up on roles authorisation. this link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin) might help. Google around a bit for more information - there's a lot.

Comment: I use a service to authenticate any user. The service returns me user's authenticity as well as its roles. I want the [Authorize(Roles="")] statement compare roles with those i get from the service.

Answer (score 1):

Roles are added to the IPrincipal of the HttpContext. You can create a GenericPrincipal, parse the list of roles in the constructor and set it as HttpContext.User. The GenericPrincipal will then be accessible through `User.IsInRole("role")` or the `[Authorize(Roles="role")]` attribute

One way of doing this (in C#) is to add your roles as a comma separated string in the user data parameter when creating your authentication ticket

```
string roles = "Admin,Member";
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
  1,
  userId,  //user id
  DateTime.Now,
  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),  // expiry
  false,  //do not remember
  roles, 
  "/");
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                                   FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Then access the role list from the authentication ticket and create a GenericPrincipal from your Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  HttpCookie authCookie = 
                Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null) {
      FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = 
                                  FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
      string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
      GenericPrincipal userPrincipal =
                       new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name),
                                            roles);
      Context.User = userPrincipal;
    }
  }
}
```

Quotation from @David Glenn